# error with real time database authentication in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Error saving rules - Line 6: Expected ':'

```
{
"rules":{
"users":{
  "$uid": {

    ".write"="$uid === auth.uid"

  }
 }

 } }
```

Can anyone help me in solving this error?

Answer (score 3):

Use this.

```
{
"rules":{
"users":{
  "$uid": {

    ".write":"$uid === auth.uid"

  }
 }
}
}
```

Key value pair in JSON is written like this `"key":"value"` , separated by `:` not `=` sign

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Kindly use : note = after ".write"

```
 {
   "rules":{
     "users":{
       "$uid": {

         ".write" : "$uid === auth.uid"

       }
     }

 } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.